# How can I make environment variables available during Vagrant provisioning?

Tags: vagrant, environment-variables, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I would like to make environment variables available to Vagrant during provisioning so that I can run some commands that rely on them for credentials. Specifically `aws cli` and `pg_restore`.

For example, `pg_restore` needs access to the $PGPASS variable which I'm setting in my `.bash_profile`. I've tried running `source /home/vagrant/.bash_profile` which exports the required AWS environment variables, but later in my provisioning block the `aws` command fails because the environment variables are not set.

.bash_profile

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='keyid'
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='secret'
```

Vagrantfile provisioning block

```
config.vm.provision :shell, run: "always", inline: <<-SH.gsub(/^\s*/,"")
  source /home/vagrant/.bash_profile
  aws s3 cp s3://bucket/sql/file /tmp/file # fail, missing credentials
  echo $(printenv | grep AWS_) # outputs blank line
SH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run the provisioning as `root` user which your bash is for `vagrant` user so make sure to run the provisioning as vagrant by adding `privileged: false`

```
config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false, run: "always", inline: <<-SH.gsub(/^\s*/,"")
  source /home/vagrant/.bash_profile
  aws s3 cp s3://bucket/sql/file /tmp/file # fail, missing credentials
  echo $(printenv | grep AWS_) # outputs blank line
SH
```

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't see the forest through the trees.